# ::after background color height adjustment on :hover

Tags: html, css, background, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I am trying to apply a color overlay to my image when hovered over. The current method i am trying is by using ::after to insert a background color when hovered over by user.

HTML

```
<div class="box-link">
    <a href="#" class="box-links-link">
       <div class="box-link-image">
           <img src="http://roctownlive.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/shutterstock_199262555-waterglass-1000x636.jpg" alt="Flowers">
       </div>
       <div class="box-link-content">
           <h2>Heading</h2>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse lobortis pretium dolor, sed tincidunt sem egestas sit amet. Sed pretium purus sed orci pharetra, sit amet egestas neque sodales.</p>
       </div>
     </a>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
box-link-image::after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(42,47,50,.6);
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: .35s , font-size 0s;
    transition: .35s , font-size 0s;
}

.box-link a:hover .box-link-image::after, .box-link a:focus .box-link-image::after, .box-link a.tap-focus .box-link-image::after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Currently when you hover over the image the background color extends to the below div where the text is, how can i make it stop where the image ends? Is this a correct method for this?

Full Codepen Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GOwYGL

Comment: Restricting it to its parent div would work fine i think.

Comment: OK. I included both examples in my answer now, just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To constrict the absolutely positioned `::after` pseudo-element to its parent div, you should position the parent too.
Note that I made the image a bit smaller, so that you can see the effect here without needing to scroll.

```css
.box-link-image {  /* new */
  position: relative;
}

.box-link-image::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(42, 47, 50, .6);
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .35s, font-size 0s;
  transition: .35s, font-size 0s;
}

.box-link a:hover .box-link-image::after,
.box-link a:focus .box-link-image::after,
.box-link a.tap-focus .box-link-image::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-link">
  <a href="#" class="box-links-link">
    <div class="box-link-image">
      <img src="http://roctownlive.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/shutterstock_199262555-waterglass-1000x636.jpg"
          style="height:150px" alt="Flowers">
    </div>
    <div class="box-link-content">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse lobortis pretium dolor, sed tincidunt sem egestas sit amet. Sed pretium purus sed orci pharetra, sit amet egestas neque sodales.</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Edit: or, if what you want is highlight only the image rather than the container div, you should shrink the div to be the same size as the image.

```css
.box-link-image {  /* new */
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
.box-link-image img {
  vertical-align:top; /* to get rid of the descender space */
}

.box-link-image::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(42, 47, 50, .6);
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .35s, font-size 0s;
  transition: .35s, font-size 0s;
}

.box-link a:hover .box-link-image::after,
.box-link a:focus .box-link-image::after,
.box-link a.tap-focus .box-link-image::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-link">
  <a href="#" class="box-links-link">
    <div class="box-link-image">
      <img src="http://roctownlive.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/shutterstock_199262555-waterglass-1000x636.jpg"
          style="height:150px" alt="Flowers">
    </div>
    <div class="box-link-content">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse lobortis pretium dolor, sed tincidunt sem egestas sit amet. Sed pretium purus sed orci pharetra, sit amet egestas neque sodales.</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Arh i see where i went wrong now. Thanks for both of those solutions i will have a look at which will work best for me.